# problem with mysql function with parameter and select

Tags: mysql, function

I have a problem with a simple mysql function that only receives one parameter, perform a select with it and if it does not succeed I need it to return a default value, the problem is that when I execute the function I receive the following error:

Procedure execution failed
1054 - Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

mysql code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_buscar_id`(pvalor  VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

   DECLARE  Pid INT;

        select ID INTO Pid from PARAMETROS_GENERALES WHERE VALOR = pvalor||' ';

   IF Pid is null THEN
      SET Pid = 514;

   END IF;

   RETURN Pid;

END;
```

no matter what you enter, you get the same error, I know it is something simple but I win ... hehe thanks for your prompt response

Comment: what result do you expect from this `VALOR = pvalor||' ';`

Comment: the idea is to use it in the where clause because the records in that column are many and all loaded with a blank space at the end

Comment: I know it's nonsense but I don't see it, I'm sorry

Comment: dont be sorry, we're learning. can you please provide sample data for 'parametros_generales' table?

Comment: yes:
CREATE TABLE `parametros_generales` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VALOR` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)

Comment: INSERT INTO parametros_generales VALUES (1,"example parameter ");

Comment: the sample data I mean.. like what is the value of ID, the value of VALOR.. example: ID will be something like 1,2,3,4. VALOR maybe something like 'this is a test', 'this is a sample', 'hello 123'

Comment: correct, they are of that data type and the concat function runs in the where?

Comment: The error message mentions `test`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in the function. How are you calling the function?

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to quote the argument: `fn_buscar_id('test')`

Comment: @DanielGregorioRodriguezGali If you want to concatenate strings, it should be `CONCAT(pvalor, ' ')`

Comment: Show how the DBA is using it, we can help you fix it.

Comment: || is shorthand for OR in mysql.

Comment: because if I execute it as SELECT `fn_buscar_id` ('h') it works perfectly for me, but if I right-click on the function (using navicat as DBA) and I execute it, it only asks me for the value and shows the error

Comment: I tried also with heidi sql and it worked well for me as well so I guess it was rather a navicat error

Comment: the same should also change the || by concat